# Oracle select not returning all columns under sqlplus

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I have the below SQL select :

```
select TST_CODE ||'|'||UTI_CODE ||'|'||TST_NAME ||'|'||TST_NAME_REDUIT ||'|'||TST_GROUP ||'|'||TST_MET ||'|'||TST_MET_CODE ||'|'||TST_MET_FAMILY ||'|'||TST_MET_CALCUL ||'|'||TNS_STATUS_PAR_NM2 ||'|'||TNS_STATUS_PART_NM1 ||'|'||TNS_STATUS_PART_N ||'|'||STR_CODE ||'|'||FOUR_CODE ||'|'||TST_SIREN ||'|'||MEMO_ASC ||'|'||NAV_FICID 
from TEST_TABLE;
```

When I run it in SQL Developer it returns my all the columns of the table.
But when I put the same request in an SQL file, like TEST_TABLE.sql and run it under sqlplus in linux it returns only the 1st 14 columns, that is it stops at FOUR_CODE.
Any idea why?

Edited:
After investigation, it is because one of the column is of data type CLOB.  Any idea how to solve this?  My  TEST_TABLE.sql is being dynamically created.

Comment: May be you are crossing the limit of character present in row https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/sqlplus.816/a75664/appc.htm

Comment: please share your `TEST_TABLE.sql` file with use to be able to reply someone.

Comment: @JayShankarGupta:  No, I know why I am getting this, because one of the columns is of date type CLOB.  Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : The file just contains the above query.  I have added to note to the question. Pls see it

Answer (score 0):

Try to enlarge LINESIZE, such as

```
SQL> set linesize 200
```

If it is not enough, enlarge it even more.