# CSV exporting causing ORA-01489

Tags: oracle, export-to-csv

I am exporting data from my Oracle 10g database to a CSV file using the spool tool.  However after exporting several rows, 184170 rows, I get the following error:

> ERROR:
>   ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

I have a field, FIELD2, in my table which is of VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) type and I have some rows which contains 4000 char.
My select request is as below:

```
select FIELD1 ||'|'||FIELD2 ||'|'||FIELD3 from table;
```

Is there any solution to this without having to truncate FIELD2?

So the problem is cause my select request is being too long.  Below is the fucntion which generates the request:

```
create or replace FUNCTION build_select (
  p_table_name   IN VARCHAR2
)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    l_ret   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
    FOR eachcol IN (  SELECT column_name, data_type
                           , LEAD (column_name)
                                 OVER (
                                     PARTITION BY table_name ORDER BY column_id
                                 )
                                 next_column
                        FROM all_tab_cols
                       WHERE table_name = p_table_name
                    ORDER BY column_id)
    LOOP
      IF eachcol.data_type = 'CLOB' THEN
        l_ret   := l_ret || 'dbms_lob.substr( '||eachcol.column_name||', 3000, 1 )'|| CASE WHEN eachcol.next_column IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ' ||''|''||' END;
      ELSE 
        l_ret   := l_ret || eachcol.column_name|| CASE WHEN eachcol.next_column IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ' ||''|''||' END;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    IF l_ret IS NULL
    THEN
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'table ' || p_table_name || ' not found');
    END IF;

    l_ret   := 'select ' || l_ret || ' from ' || p_table_name || ';';

    RETURN l_ret;
END build_select;
```

Comment: use `SET colsep '|' `  to get  pipe separated records. Run query simply as  `select field1,field2,field3 from table`

Comment: @KaushikNayak : No I can't do this cause I have a function which build my select request like this.

Comment: Then change your function. Otherwise you may have to use `CLOB`.

Comment: @KaushikNayak:  This is what my question is about.  If I use CLOB the csv generated will not contain all the rows.  I am exporting CLOB using the dbms_lob.substr function.

Comment: Where in the question have you explained that you have a a function or  "exporting CLOB using the `dbms_lob.substr` ? Clearly explain what you are trying to achieve and  provide some background  in the question which could be useful to find a solution and to avoid confusion.

Comment: My question has nothing with CLOB data type.  You proposed using CLOB as solution, I said that CLOB can't be the solution.  MY problem is with the data type VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) which is causing the above error upon CSV exporting.  I have provided the select request used for spooling and I am trying to find a solution for the error I got.

Comment: The procedure you show is not related to the error you get. Post the query, not the code which generates it.

Comment: You struggle with this rather simple problem for a week, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022980/spool-not-exporting-all-columns, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023948/oracle-select-not-returning-all-columns-under-sqlplus, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104591/csv-exporting-causing-ora-01489) - maybe you should look for a different approach. What about writing a small Perl script for example? I assume you would get less trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said

> FIELD2, in my table which is of  is VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) and you have some rows which
>   contains 4000 char,

It will cause no problem when selecting columns as `select field1,field2,field3`. But, because you are concatenating it all together using "|" , the final string is exceeding 4000 characters, which is the limit for a `VARCHAR2` column. So, Oracle throws error because you cannot have even an aliased column with an implicit datatype of `VARCHAR2`, that exceeds 4000 characters.

One option is to use

```
set colsep '|'
```

in your SQL* Plus session and simply selecting it as

`select field1,field2,field3 from yourtable` .

Another option is to explicitly cast the result as `CLOB`, using the `TO_CLOB` function.

```
select TO_CLOB(NULL)||FIELD1 ||'|'||FIELD2 ||'|'||FIELD3 from table;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce6c7/18)

Comment: So you mean it is the result which is in the form DATA1||DATA2||DATA3 which is exceeding 4000 characters which is causing this error?

Comment: @tabby : Exactly. Why was it so confusing to you? simply run a `select field2 from yourtable` for the record that is 4000 chars long, Has it ever not worked for you?

Comment: The thing is that I need my select request to be in the form DATA1||DATA2||DATA3 so as to reduce the size of the CSV generated.  I have a function which does this.  And for CLOB type I have a condition in my function : IF eachcol.data_type = 'CLOB' THEN
        l_ret   := l_ret || 'dbms_lob.substr( '||eachcol.column_name||', 3000, 1 )'|| CASE WHEN eachcol.next_column IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ' ||''|''||' END;  Maybe I can try something similar?

Comment: @tabby : If that's the case, you should update your question with the part of the function code with the details of how you are generating your select statement. Perhaps, you may also have to modify your function.

Comment: Ok, I modified the question.

Comment: Or is there a way to increase the 4000 value?